# Change mouse cursor across environment with AutoIt

Tags: autoit

I'm hoping this is feasible... I made a program using AutoIt that resides in the system tray. One of the tray items runs a function that waits for the user to click on a window to get the window title (it can be any window, not necessarily one made from AutoIt. This part works flawlessly.

I would like for the function to change the mouse cursor to the cross while waiting for the user's click. I have tried using GUISetCursor(3), but from my understanding this only changes the cursor for an AutoIt GUI window.

How could I go about changing the mouse cursor for the user's environment, not just for an AutoIt window?

Comment: You can adapt this article https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/01/17/use-powershell-to-change-the-mouse-pointer-scheme/ to AutoIt, but I think it would be practice to do so because the change wouldn't be automatically restored when your program quits

Comment: Thanks for a point in the right direction, along with a user in the AutoIt forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thatnks to Richard's comment, and a reply in the AutoIt forums that linked me to AutoIt's [_WinAPI_SetSystemCursor](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_WinAPI_SetSystemCursor.htm) function, I was able to get this working.

I copied the cross cursor I wanted from %SystemRoot%\Cursors (specifically, I copied cross_i.cur) to put in my script's source directory.

Then, in the function that executes the brute of the program, I added the following lines:

```
Func FuncName()
       ;backs up the user's arrow cursor
   Local $hPrev = _WinAPI_CopyCursor(_WinAPI_LoadCursor(0, 32512))

       ;backs up the user's ibeam cursor
   Local $iPrev = _WinAPI_CopyCursor(_WinAPI_LoadCursor(0, 32513)) 

       ;changes the user's arrow cursor
   _WinAPI_SetSystemCursor(_WinAPI_LoadCursorFromFile(@ScriptDir & "\cross.cur"),32512) 
       ;changes the user's ibeam cursor
   _WinAPI_SetSystemCursor(_WinAPI_LoadCursorFromFile(@ScriptDir & "\cross.cur"),32513) 

   ; Do the code you want to execute

       ;restores the user's default cursor
   _WinAPI_SetSystemCursor($hPrev,32512) 
       ;restores the user's ibeam cursor
   _WinAPI_SetSystemCursor($iPrev,32513) 
EndFunc
```

This allowed me to accomplish what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it so:

```
#include <Misc.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>

GetTitleByClick()

Func GetTitleByClick()
    Local $hCursor = GUICreate('', 48, 48, -1, -1, $WS_POPUP, $WS_EX_TOPMOST)
    WinSetTrans($hCursor, '', 10)
    GUISetCursor(3, 1, $hCursor)
    GUISetState(@SW_SHOW, $hCursor)

    ; get title bar position
    Local $pos
    Do
        $pos = MouseGetPos()
        WinMove($hCursor, '', $pos[0]-24, $pos[1]-24)
        Sleep(10)
    Until _IsPressed('01')
    GUIDelete($hCursor)

    ; block mouse
    _MouseTrap($pos[0], $pos[1], $pos[0]+1, $pos[0]+1)

    ; click position - activates the window
    MouseClick('left', $pos[0], $pos[1])

    ; unblock mouse
    _MouseTrap()

    ; get the title of the active window
    Local $sTitle = WinGetTitle('[ACTIVE]')

    Return MsgBox(0, 'TITLE', $sTitle)
EndFunc
```

Comment: I appreciate the input, but I don't think I was originally clear in what I wanted... I have the algorithm for gathering the user's click on the window; what I did not have was changing the cursor. I have found my answer through a couple various sources. I have modified my question to what I hope is more clear